# PHP custom session path: folder not used

Tags: php

For a multiple domain website, I've set my own session path - using `session_save_path()` - as I'm on a shared hosting environment. Here is my code :

```
$seoDomain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$sessionPath = '/home/whatever/sessions' .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$seoDomain;  

ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3*60*60); // 3 hours
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 100);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', true);

if (!is_dir($sessionPath)) {
    mkdir($sessionPath, 0775, true);
}

session_save_path($sessionPath);
session_start();
```

I've check if it was correctly set using `ini_get('session.save_path')`. Everything looks fine. However nothing gets written in the specific folder. As my sessions are still running perfectly well, I've supposed they are stored in the default folder.

What did I miss ?

Comment: what distribution has your server?